# Constexpr локальные переменные

Tags: c++

Пусть имеется такой код:

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int x = 0;
}
```

Известно, что значение x вычисляется на этапе компиляции и что constexpr - типобезопасная замена #define. Также x - локальная переменная, локальные переменные выделяются на стеке.

Где будет храниться значение x? На стеке? По идее не должно быть так, потому что это работает как #define, а дефайны на стеке не выделяются. Есть ли класс памяти у constexpr единиц хранения?

Comment: Эксперимент с g++ показывает, что в стеке. И он же показывает, что это неважная замена для `#define`, поскольку хранимую там "константу" можно менять.

Comment: @avp, можете привести пример? Очень интересно как можно изменить константу времени компиляции. У меня вот [не вышло](http://cpp.sh/4f6j7)

Comment: @avp, А вот изменить значение `#define` [куда проще](http://cpp.sh/3mpy3)

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, передав адрес в отдельную единицу компиляции. После этого обращение по адресу дает новое значение. Правда, стоит отметить, что обращения по имени дают начальное (такой, вот, шизофренический язык С++)

Comment: @avp, обычное неопределенное поведение. На платформе с защищенной от записи памятью упадет с сегфолтом и всего делов

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, стек, защищенный от записи? (далее уже *no comments*)

Answer (score 3):

С формально-абстрактной точки зрения вы предоставили *определение* локального объекта, которое трактуется по общим правилам для локальных объектов - `x` будет иметь обычный автоматический storage duration, как у обычной локальной переменной. `constexpr` на это никак не виляет.

А будет ли `x` фактически где-то храниться - это уже решение принимаемое компилятором. Если объект не является odr-used в программе, то и определения для него не требуется, т.е. фактически хранить его где-либо нет никакой необходимости (независимо от константности такого объекта). То есть говорить о хранении объекта, который не является odr-used - довольно бессмысленное занятие.

В вашем случае `x` не является odr-used, потому и хранить его нигде фактически не надо. Не существует способа проверить где "хранится" `x` не сделав `x` odr-used, т.е. пытаться выяснить это путем эксперимента будет бесполезным занятием - именно ваш эксперимент и будет причиной "хранения".

Вот в такой программе

```
int main()
{
  constexpr int x = 0;
  int a[x + 1];
  std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

`x` тоже не является odr-used и храниться где-то совсем не обязан.